# recursive function without recursive prompt

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to call recursive factorial function in javascript, but prompt keeps on going.

```
function recursiveFactorial() {
        var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Number: "));
        if (a === 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            facValue = (a * recursiveFactorial(a - 1));

        }
        alert("The factorial of " + a + " is: " + facValue);

}
```

Comment: Place the prompt outside the function and pass the value of the prompt to the function

Comment: What happens when call a (recursive) function? Why do you think the prompt and the alert should not appear again if you call the function recursively?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The else case gets called and directly after that the alert gets called (just line by line).
so set a return statement underneath the facValue uns the else statement. That way you do not come to the part of the alert. And then put  the alert outside the recursive function, as you only want to show the final result.

Comment: `facValue` should not be a global. Use `const` or `let` to declare it in the function.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this,the first is to move the prompt and facValue outside of the the recursive function,the second is to set the prompt and facValue as the parameter of the recursive function,I show the second one below,

```
function recursiveFactorial(number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Number: ")), a = number, facValue = 1) {
    if (a === 0) {
        alert("The factorial of " + number + " is: " + facValue);
    } else {
        recursiveFactorial(number, a - 1, a * facValue);
    }
}
```